# How to redirect a category page link to CMS page link in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite, cms-pages

I want to redirect my category link to some cms page. Could anyone tell me how to do so? Any help will be appreciated.

---

@Kho TruongDinh As you specified, I have used URL rewrite, but it did not work for me..

What I really did is... I created a category 'Type', and I created a cms page for that category as 'type-page'.

Then I went to URL rewrites.

[image]

I wrote a URL rewrite as below.
[image]
But now, the redirect is not working, it still shows the default category page. Any solution????

Comment: Use https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you created a wrong url rewrite.

**"Request path"** is the path that you actually see in your browser's address bar. So in your case it should be `type.html` instead of `"catalog/category/view/id/4`.

Before doing this, you should know that in case you already have a category with `type.html` **url key** then **Magento** will not allow you to create a new url rewrite with the same request path. So firstly you need to find and delete the existing url rewrite.

I've just tried this steps on my local machine and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the cms page content into static block. Then create a category and assign that block to that category.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this below links :-

http://iamrookie.com/blog/319/redirect-category-link-cms-page-link-magento.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rSIQlRC8Xk

Answer (score 0):

That's work but the block it was inserted in the section category-view and not in the content main but i removed that section

`<referenceBlock name="main" remove="true" />`

i applied this just in the category

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your category is goes to `wholesale.html` and you want to redirect to a the CMS page `whole-sale`. Try doing what you see in the following screenshot.

[image]